# Insert missing rows in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df = 
       lb    mean  median 
HEAX  0.02    2.37   1.18
HAX   0.00    1.09   0.17
HEA   0.09    7.29   5.95
EAX   43.50  104.42  96.66
```

Some rows are missing in it. i.e the index of the rows that are missing in the dataframe is
present in a list.

```
ls = ["HEAX", "AXE", "HAX", "HEA", "AEX", "EAX"]
```

I want to generate the following

```
       lb    mean  median 
HEAX  0.02    2.37   1.18
AXE
HAX   0.00    1.09   0.17
HEA   0.09    7.29   5.95
AEX
EAX   43.50  104.42  96.66
```

I tried something like below

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=range(0, len(ls)), columns=df.columns)
temp_df.index = ls
temp_df = temp_df.set_index('index').fillna(df.set_index('index')).reset_index()
```

bu this returns an error

```
KeyError: "None of ['index'] are in the columns"
```

I'd like to know how to do this in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `reindex`

```
df = df.reindex(ls)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this helps. May I know how the missing rows can be inserted in a similar way if the index column posted above is actually a column in the dataframe with colume name = `id`